# DuplicateKeyException alternative for javax.persistence

Tags: java, persistence, key, duplication

Is there something like of *DuplicateKeyException* applicable to javax.persistence.*?

I've found this exception for ejb lib only: [DuplicateKeyException](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/ejb/DuplicateKeyException.html)

Thank you.

Comment: Nope, you can always make one though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javax.persistence.EntityExistsException is what you will usually get from a JPA provider if you try to save something that as a duplicate key.